# I m facing issue in Coding this rotation part in cics

Tags: mainframe, cics

How can we rotate CUSTOMER NUMBER values in CICS? 
For eg. If customer number is c52063
How can i get onto next value ie, c52064(say) in CICS?

Comment: What language ???

Comment: What language ???; What have you tried ???; Have you ask at around; Most sites would have a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *very* broad question, essentially you're asking what persistence mechanisms are available in CICS.

Please understand there is a big difference between...

- what is technically possible
- what is allowed in your shop
- what is likely to provide a robust and maintainable solution given your requirements

These are three very different things.  Some of us answering questions here on StackOverflow have life experiences that make us reticent about answering questions regarding what is technically possible absent any mention of what is allowed in your shop or what the actual business requirement that is being solved.

Mainframes have been around for over half a century, and many shops have standard solutions to technical problems.  Sometimes the solution is "don't do that, and here's what *we* do instead."  Working against the recommendations of your technical staff, or your shop standards, is career limiting.

A couple of options, not intended to be an exhaustive list...

- `SELECT` and `UPDATE` the value in a DBMS (such as DB2).  You must code your `SELECT` SQL with `FOR UPDATE`.
- `READ` and `REWRITE` the value in a VSAM file.  You must code your `READ` with the `UPDATE` option.

In either case you are holding a lock on the resource until you hit either an explicit (`EXEC CICS SYNCPOINT`) or implicit (end of transaction) syncpoint or rollback (`EXEC CICS SYNCPOINT ROLLBACK` or abend condition).  Holding such a lock means all other instances of your transaction will wait until the syncpoint or rollback has occurred.

*If you know* ***for certain*** *your application will be limited to a single CICS region...*  Other options would include having a transaction initiated as part of region initialization processing that would obtain and populate a shared resource such as a temporary storage queue with a name known to your application with the last known customer number.  This initialization transaction would have to obtain the highest used customer number from somewhere, probably a DBMS or a VSAM file.  Applications would have to be coded to ENQ and DEQ their access to the temporary storage queue.  You could do this without using a temporary storage queue but with shared memory and storing the address of that memory in the CICS CWA for your region.  Again, ENQ and DEQ logic would have to be coded in the applications.

You could use a named counter as defined by your CICS Systems Programmer.  Be certain to read and understand the recovery requirements for your application as documented in the IBM Knowledge Center.

Again, this is not an exhaustive list, it is just to give an overview of some of the options available.  Talk to your technical staff, they likely have either a standard solution as employed by your shop or a preference based on their experience and your requirements.